# Reading faster strings from url

Tags: c#

I have a little problem when reading strings from URL which is .m3u8 files that contains links
my code takes about 1min to finish reading the strings. I don't know but my internet connection is fine
maybe there's little improvement you could suggest.

Here's the example .m3u8 link:

> https://d1k2us671qcoau.cloudfront.net/vodapi/viu_aws.m3u8?vid=ec69210abb3af50db3893048494b4872&layer=Layer4&ts=202007011038&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kMWsydXM2NzFxY29hdS5jbG91ZGZyb250Lm5ldC92b2RhcGkvKiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTU5MzU4NTUzOX19fV19&Signature=bl6FkmmIJQr5hLuMrssfo1eO8PiKM9XsfwU7d8-E8AEXttO6sOaj8XtibarbvqdEUOGy59qyAN6r7U-vFdChPrL80~Vv5ifxoLJagqp2WeYbXJZPztquHEnHjEClCGeCOExz6QhlsjFMXjTfXcmzyvpum2e-WlO6w6ZNHSR3PhxH8ms9UW9zdzZYoMTsLVzKErN2PdrxKDSfOX9N31VxfcEUHVz3fkwrmYN4Nqbhaza2LdqDJ9sfPOxtVfFHgcQyJaZAk5pjkjz3vAj-sS5KQxxmVOEXCTEIfad-xl2ltpxlVbcItSmtErOoASKiNNYW7DiFg6ancJlyjqaE7UiRhw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJ6Z4RF5IYK7Y3SQQ

```
private readonly string urlPattern = "(https.+)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";

      async Task readURLAsync(string url, TextBox result)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidationCallback);
         
            try
            {
                IsReading(true);
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                HttpWebRequest Request = await Task.Run(() => (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri));
                Request.Proxy = null;
                Request.Method = "GET";
                Request.UserAgent = cbUserAgent.Text;
                Request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
                Request.Headers.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
                Request.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";

                using (WebResponse Response = await Task.Run(() => Request.GetResponse()))
                {
                    using (StreamReader Reader = await Task.Run(() => new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())))
                    {
                        string content = await Reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(content, urlPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        foreach (Match m in mc)
                        {
                            sb.Append(m.Value + "\r\n");
                        }

                        result.Text = sb.ToString().Trim();
                        CountLinks();

                        if (textBox_Result.Text.Trim() == "")
                            return;
                    }
                }
                if (Request != null)
                {
                    Request.Abort();
                }
            }

            catch (HttpRequestException ex2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            IsReading(false);
        }
```

Comment: Improvements **1)** use the more modern `HttpClient` from the `HttpClientFactory` **2)** Stop *offloading* IO bound workloads to `Task.Run` there should be no `Task.Run` in this code except for maybe the `CountLines` however you have lost your `Task.Run` privilege's as of now  **3)** use the native *async* methods of `HttpClient` see 1 & 2 respectively, **4)** If your connection and the remote resources are fast, then the code is most likely spending its time in `CountLinks`

Comment: What's the point of doing `await Task.Run`?

Comment: @Enigmativity it makes you feel better about life `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @TheGeneral - I wonder if changing the code to be like `result.Text = await Task.Run(() => sb.ToString().Trim());` will lead to greater happiness?

Comment: @Enigmativity happiness level would equal 100, though the code reviewers happiness would be at an all time low

Comment: @TheGeneral - What about `if (await Task.Run(() => Request) != null)`?

Comment: @TheGeneral - No, wait, what about this? `if (await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Run(() => Request)) != null)`

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks for the suggestion. I'm new in reading online strings. I'll take a look at it.
Regarding with Task.Run. if I can't put them my app is freezing.

Comment: @Enigmativity lots more happiness ? yes i think that's what would happen

Comment: @zackmark15 use the *async and await pattern*, with `HttpClients` native `async` calls, would be the best bet. if your time is spent with in CountLines, you could then offload it to `await Task.Run`

Comment: Alright. I'll try using httpclients. I'll post if I succeed :)

Comment: @zackmark15 - Separate out all access to UI controls in your code and then wrap the whole thing in a `Task.Run` and then invoke the result out to the UI when it is done. The app won't freeze at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest getting down to something more like this:

```
Task<string> readURLAsync(string url, string userAgent)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Method", "GET");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(userAgent);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string readResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(readResponse, urlPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, mc.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow this is what I'm trying to do to separate the ui but I can't succeed
Thank you so much for this I tried and it worked.

Comment: May I ask one last question?
How about if header are not toLower?
because other site use capital letter at the beginning like "Accept-Language", Accept"

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Alright here's what I did according to all your suggestions.
First time to try httpclient and it success.

How i can set the proxy to null? because with using httpwebrequest it can speed up reading the content if proxy is set to null.

maybe you can suggest more changes so that I can improve this codes

```
  async Task readURLAsync(string url, TextBox output)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidationCallback);

        try
        {
            IsReading(true);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Method", "GET");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(cbUserAgent.Text);
           
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    //   var success = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    string readResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(readResponse, urlPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (Match m in mc)
                    {
                        sb.Append(m.Value + "\r\n");
                    }

                    output.Text = await Task.Run(() => sb.ToString().Trim());
                    CountLinks();
                }
            }
        }

        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        IsReading(false);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, doing `await Task.Run(() => sb.ToString().Trim());` was meant to be a joke.

Comment: My comment "Separate out all access to UI controls in your code and then wrap the whole thing in a `Task.Run` and then invoke the result out to the UI when it is done. The app won't freeze at all.", however, was not a joke.